Nextcloud composer - podman network dies
My current setup on debian bookworm, with podman, podman containers running with lowered privileges.
nextcloud is running.
After a while, the exposed route is not responding anymore (send-q increasing with ss/netstat)
Current setup

The host is a debian bookworm, with podman 2.3 (stock in debian)
there is a compose.yaml file (reported below) to run nextcloud
nextcloud apache have a route from host localhost:11000 to container port 80
nextcloud is running with an unprivileged ID
apache, running on the host, is acting as reverse proxy
the mysql host is on the host
redis is there, but not in use (yet)

Expected behaviour
nextcloud goes up and replies to the HTTP call, "forever"
Current behaviour
nextcloud goes up and replies to the HTTP call, but after a while,
podman stops routing the communication from port 11000 of the host to the container.
i was tcpdump on the podman network, and i can't see any tcp packet moving to the container.
i am unable to see any packet moving through after that the issue start.
Feel free to ask for any further detail.
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:

services:
  redis:
    image: docker.io/library/redis:alpine
    container_name: nextcloud-redis

  app:
    image: docker.io/library/nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud-app
    user: 1003:1003
    sysctls:  # Necessary for user: ${PUID}:${PGID} # https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/755
      - net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start=0 # Allow an unprivileged user to listen on any port https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/359 https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/458
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:11000:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/cloud.[redacted]/private/nextcloud/:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=[redacted]
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=host.containers.internal
    depends_on:
      - redis

  cron:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud-cron
    user: 1003:1003
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www/cloud.[redacted]/private/nextcloud/:/var/www/html
    entrypoint: /cron.sh
    depends_on:
      - redis

